# PHP domDocument to remove child nodes of a child node

Tags: php, xml, dom, document

How do I remove a parent node of a child node, but keep all the children?

The XML file is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<products>
<product>
<ItemId>531<ItemId>
<modelNumber>00000</modelNumber>
<categoryPath>
<category><name>Category A</name></category>
<category><name>Category B</name></category>
<category><name>Category C</name></category>
<category><name>Category D</name></category>
<category><name>Category E</name></category>
</categoryPath>
</product>
</products>
```

Basically, I need to remove the categoryPath node and the category node, but keep all of the name nodes inside of the product node. What I am aiming for is a document like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
<products>
<product>
<ItemId>531<ItemId>
<modelNumber>00000</modelNumber>
<name>Category A</name>
<name>Category B</name>
 <name>Category C</name>
<name>Category D</name>
<name>Category E</name>
</product>
</products>
```

Is there PHP built in function to do this? Any pointers would be appreciated, I just do not know where to start because there are many child nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach to process XML data is to use the [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) facility.

It's quite easy once you get introduced to it. For example:

```
<?php

// load up your XML
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('input.xml');

// Find all elements you want to replace. Since your data is really simple,
// you can do this without much ado. Otherwise you could read up on XPath.
// See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php
$elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName('category');

// WARNING: $elements is a "live" list -- it's going to reflect the structure
// of the document even as we are modifying it! For this reason, it's
// important to write the loop in a way that makes it work correctly in the
// presence of such "live updates".
while($elements->length) {
    $category = $elements->item(0); 
    $name = $category->firstChild; // implied by the structure of your XML 

    // replace the category with just the name 
    $category->parentNode->replaceChild($name, $category); 
} 

// final result:
$result = $xml->saveXML();
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X1Xl6P)**.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I saw it is only removing every other category tag. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @Ben: Actually, no. Give me a second to fix this.

Comment: @Ben: Fixed, I got caught by some... interesting... behavior of `DOMNodeList`. See [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php#99716) for an explanation of what happened; you could rewrite the `for` as indicated in that comment to fix the issue, but I preferred a `while` because it looks natural even if you don't know what's going on and why such a strange way of writing a `for` is required.

Comment: Oh ok. I read over the document on php.net. Great. To remove categoryPath, I can use some of the parts of the code you wrote right? It will work if I use getElementsByTagName and then use removeChild?

Comment: @Ben: Code is meant to be reusable :) although I 'm not sure what you are suggesting to do. But I think you got the idea.

Comment: In order to remove the categoryPath tag but keep the children (all the name tags), can I use this code for that?